# How can I display different weights/styles of interstate font?

Tags: font-face, embedded-fonts

I have uploaded the font onto my computer and I will upload it to the server but I don't know how to write it in my code. I want to use "Interstate" but only "Interstate Black Condensed."

I tried changing the weights or adding that in the name but it just goes to a default font. The only way Interstate works is if I just write "Interstate," but the bold works but it does not give me the black category.

```
.numbers {
   font-family:Interstate;
   font-weight: 300;
   font-size:30pt;
   text-align:center;
   color:#3baa4d;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Interstate Black Condensed version of the font I would recommend using a tool to generate a font face declaration for it, while converting the file for web use. This generator should do the trick:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

All you have to do is upload the Interstate Black Condensed file to that site, then include the font files it gives you in your project, then paste the font-face code at the top of your css file.